# getting vertices and face as numpy array from a stl file using trimesh

Tags: python, trimesh, numpy-stl

I have an STL file, I now need to read the vertices and face value of that STL file using trimesh.

```
 myobj = trimesh.load_mesh("file.stl", enable_post_processing=True, solid=True) 
 myobj.faces #gives me ndarray of faces
```

how to read vertices from myobj ?

Answer (score 1):

```
myobj.vertices
```

[Here's the document](https://trimsh.org/trimesh.base.html?#trimesh.base.Trimesh.vertices)